# Shell script run by a GitBash process created by Java's ProcessBuilder cannot read files

Tags: java, bash, process

I am using a shell script to request an api to analyze an image (stored remotely, url given as parameter to the script) and read the output which will be further processed. The script reads from a file containing a key to authenticate myself. When I run the script from terminal it read the file as normal, but when run by a git bash process created by the ProcessBuilder class it cannot interact with directories entirely. For example the ls command returns blank when run on a nonempty readable executable directory.

java snippet:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe", "-c", "src/hash_methods/AzureVision/analyze-img.txt");
        pb.directory(new File("./")); //i checked the path, trus me
        Process process = pb.start();

        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        String result = builder.toString();
}
```

analyze-img.txt:

```
    #!/usr/bin/bash
    key="$(cat $(pwd)/src/hash_methods/AzureVision/resource_key.txt)"
    #again i checked the path
    endpoint="redacted"
    echo $key #outputs blank
    #Code to call a service for image analysis
```

Permissions might come into play here, the files are all accessible, but the java or bash process might not have them in which case i don't know how to give it to them.

Comment: Look at the error stream, or redirect error to stdout, and also read the error code. Both should give a clue. By the way `./` is current directory so could be omitted.

Comment: *echo $key #outputs blank* Then you already have a problem right there, which needs to be solved first. That's not a good approach anyway as it ties your code to a specific location. You need something more solid. Never ignore stderr

Comment: You can make your code a whole lot easier by appending `.inheritIO();` to the constructor. All code after `start()` can go until it's working

Comment: Thanks guys, I followed the error trail and found that /c/Program Files/Git/bin wasn't being added to PATH in the .bashrc file

Comment: Although when I update .bashrc, the commands will work, yet echo $PATH gives the old one still.

Comment: Probably a good idea to post that part of.bashrc